# Can the creator of the App provide collateral for the user?

Tags: wallet, collateral

Consider integrated devices that use the Cardano blockchain, where the user does not see the wallet, but the wallet is working in the background

Is it possible to have this type of app supply collateral on behalf of the user from a wallet that the app developer controls? So the user doesn't need to send collateral to their new wallet

Looking for ways to solve the degraded UX of having to add collateral to new wallets before interacting with smart contracts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, collateral is just an UTXO, the dApp backend could provide one to be used and sign the transaction on the backend.

Also, regarding the bad UX, with the changes in the last hard fork, there is no need to setup collateral anymore and dApps can use any utxo.